# Is there a way to delete all cells at once in jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter

I everyday try out my solutions before answering a pandas question in stack overflow . Usually after two to three days the jupyter notebook I use will be with n number of cells. Is there a way to delete all cells at once other than creating new notebook by deleting current one?

`D D` deletes one cell at a time.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can delete all Jupyter notebook's cells at once as follows:

1. Select all cells : `ESC + SHIFT + DOWN` (starting from the top)
2. Then click `ESC + D D` (D twice)

Comment: Awesome wasnt aware of selecting at all. Thank you @MedAli

Comment: how to undo deleted cell  ?

Comment: @pyd click `z` in the keyboard

Comment: Still would be nice if Jupyter had a command to select all (Shift + down arrow is more of a "scrolling" solution). But this works.

Comment: To select all, indeed scrolling down with the down arrow takes a long time because everything is displayed.  This is faster: select (click) the first cell, then scroll down with the window scrolling bar and `SHIFT` select the last cell. (JNB version 6.1.4.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Hit `esc` to exit edit mode
2. Click to select the topmost cell you want to delete. in jupyterlab, a blue vertical line appears to the cell's left.
3. Hit `end` to scroll to the bottom of the notebook
4. Shift-click the last cell (similar to step 2) to select the range of cells to delete.
5. Hit `d, d` to delete all the selected cells.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

- `<ESC><CTRL-A>` Select all cells
- `<ESC><D><D>`   Delete all selected cells

`<ESC>P` will bring up the list of commands and key bindings