# Jupyter table of contents sometimes becomes blank. How to fix without restarting?

Tags: jupyter-lab

Sometimes jupyter lab's table of contents blanks itself.

I have a long running notebook that takes a long time to run in notebook. If I have it open for too long the table of contents side bar becomes blank. This is quite annoying, because I like to use the table of contents to find things in a notebook. How can I get the table of contents back without restarting? Is there a way of getting a sidebar table of contents which won't do this?

I'm using jupyter lab version 3.4.8.

## Workarounds

- Finally found "heading menu / sidebar" that works with firefox [a11y-outline](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/a11y-outline/) . This uses a modal screen rather than a sidebar and seems to work out.
- In another stack overflow question (can't find it right now). I found someone suggested changing the "Include cell output in headings" Advanced > Table of contents > "Include cell output in headings" to off - this fixed the bug

### Approaches I tried

- [Generating the toc manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39817243/1892584) this is a bunch of effort however
- I tried the firefox [headings map](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/headingsmap/) extension to work around firefox  - that looked like it would quite well but it appears to break the display of jupyter so that the panes are too small. I get the same problem in [outline sidebar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/outline-sidebar/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search) and [page structure](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/outline-sidebar/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search). I wish jupyter was less clever...  [Skip to headings and landmarks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/skipto/) does not break the layout in the same way - but also does not work.

## Related question

[This talks about a table of contents that is *always* missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55065406/table-of-contents-disappeared-in-jupyter-notebook)